# (Laravel) Auth on OnePager

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I installed Laravel Auth and created an index.blade.php with a login/register mask, as a OnePager (i.e. two forms that exchange himself (clicking button)

However, I am currently despairing of realizing the login with Laravel in the first form.

"/login" leads to the normal Laravel login page, of course, but how do I include the login mask from my index.blade.php and route the whole thing to the index?

(Later it will redirect normally to "/dashboard" as it is with Laravel)

If that is understood for the login, it is simultaneously with the register.

I set the form method to POST and action to `{{ route('login') }}` and that didn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The login form has the same csrf token as the register form. How can I make both forms get their own token without reloading the page?

Comment: Hi, this  fits better as an edit, an update to your question. This is not an answer. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for better understanding Stack Overflow rules